# How to make a pivot table that counts from multiple columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets, pivot-table, spreadsheet

I have a workday schedule in which I will count how many times I do each activity across the week. Here's an example:
[image]

The pivot table only allows me to count from MWF or TT but not from both without doing some weird nesting. For example, I want to see the following:

```
Labels            Count

Sleep              8
H: Lift weights    2
Commute to office  2
...
```

I tried MS Excel and Google Sheets and couldn't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: You can do this easily in Power Query.  First unpivot the data columns so as to create a two column table showing Time and Task.  Then Group by Task and aggregate by Count.

Answer (score 1):

That's just how pivot tables work. The aggregation only works on one column.

But you can easily do the count with a CountIf(). Build a table of unique values, like in column E in the screenshot and then plug them into CountIf() like below.

```
=COUNTIF(B:C,E2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may choose your table, right click it > Get Data from Range/Table. Please remembre to tick this box of My table has Headers.

Choose these 2 columns, right click the data > Unpivot Columns.

[image]

Then Choose "Value" column, right click it > Group By, count rows based on Value, then you would get the result table.

[image]

[image]

Go to File tab > Close&Load To > Pivot Table Report.

[image]